# How can I delete a printer from CUPS?

Tags: linux, printing, cups

My local CUPS server is confused about the name of the printer I use.  It has two names: `hpext` and `hpext@vm-cups`.  I can never predict which one is going to work, and if I use the wrong one, jobs just sit in its queue indefinitely.

There are no printers listed in `/etc/cupsd/cupsd.conf`; instead I have the line

```
BrowsePoll cups.eecs.tufts.edu
```

This server lists only `hpext` and not `hpext@vm-cups`.
I'm thinking that somehow my local server is confused, and if I can delete the printer from its memory, all will be well.  But nowhere in the documentation can I find a command to delete a printer, and the DELETE PRINTER button on the stupid web interface has no effect.

What can I do?

Comment: did you take a look at lpadmin's man page?.. lpadmin helps you to manage cups' printers

Comment: @Luciano: dammit, lpadmin -x was there the whole time.  Please write an answer so I can upvote and accept.

Comment: Alright, done !

Answer (score 28, accepted):

lpadmin helps you to manage cups' printers

Try

```
man lpadmin
```

I believe what you need is

```
lpadmin -x
```

Comment: Maybe it's useful to list the printers before removing: `lpstats -s`

Comment: Think it should be `lpstat -s`.

Comment: there is no option `-x`

Answer (score 5):

1. On web, enter http://localhost:631/printers/
2. Click on printer to be deleted.
3. Select `Delete Printer` in `Administration` drop-down list.
4. Confirm `Delete Printer` by clicking on it.

Comment: After pressing "Delete Printer" (step 4) I got an error "Forbidden". I needed to use Luciano Facchinelli's solution - `lpstat -s` to find the printer name, then `sudo lpadmin -x [printer name from lpstat -s]`

Comment: doing this makes the printer immedately appear again. this is no use.

Answer (score 1):

The other way around this would be to turn off automatic browsing of Network Printers and just add the one printer you want manually. I think the reason the Delete button "has no effect" is that CUPS is getting a broadcast/notification that a "new" printer is available on the network.

Addition: If you don't want to lose those printers you already have, add them to your local CUPS instead of relying on broadcast.

Comment: I don't want to lose the color printer, the high-speed copier, etc.

Comment: That might be my problem. I have a working EpsonWF3540 printer I configured, and a broken unwanted EPSON_WF_3540_Series. I removed the bogus printer from CUPS admin at http://localhost:631/printers/ , I even removed its /etc/cups/ppd/EPSON_WF_3540_Series.ppd, but it still shows up in print dialogs and in `lpstat -e -l` output. Cups Help > Using Network Printers suggests `lpinfo --include-schemes dnssd -v` to find printer URIs, and sure enough there's a "network dnssd://EPSON%20WF-3540%20Series._ipp._tcp.local/?uuid=7c47f900-67ff-11d4-9a7f-b0e89210ad1e"